# Change User Group Front-End

Tags: users, user-groups

I've got a client project which utilizes the Users section of craft pretty heavily. I am trying to figure out if it is possible in vanilla craft to move a user from one group to another say, from the 'employee' group to the 'manager' group. I have seen some code to do it in a custom controller action in a few other posts on here, but I'd rather avoid creating a custom plugin for this if possible.

So is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to do this from a [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) that has a [controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers) that calls [UserGroupsService->assignUserToGroups()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserGroupsService#assignUserToGroups-detail).