# Allow logged in user to change his own user group using front end form

Tags: user-groups

I'd like to allow a user to change his user group via front end form.  I tried passing the `groupId` as the destination group, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I was passing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="groupId" value="2">
```

I came across [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10045/change-user-group-front-end) and am thinking that it's not possible to do without a plugin.